# Python list generation pitfall

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

## Attempt 1

```
>>> width = 3
>>> height = 2
```

```
>>> zeros = [[0]*width]*height
>>> print(zeros)
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
>>> zeros[1][2] = "foo"
>>> print(zeros)
[[0, 0, 'foo'], [0, 0, 'foo']]
```

Expected result was `[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 'foo']]`. It seems that the `*` operator populated each row with references to the same object, so modifying `zeros[1]` also modified `zeros[0]`.

## Attempt 2

So now we create the initial list object using list comprehension instead:

```
>>> zeros = [[0 for i in range(width)] for j in range(height)]
>>> print(zeros)
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
>>> zeros[1][2] = "foo"
>>> print(zeros)
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 'foo']]
```

Great, this is the expected result.

## The question is...

If the `*` operator populates each *row* with references to the same object, then why doesn't *every element within each row* refer to the same object?

That is, with a (partial) understanding of why **Attempt 1** didn't produce the expected output, I would expect that if ANY element of `zeros` is modified, ALL elements would be changed, that is:

```
>>> zeros = [[0]*width]*height
>>> print(zeros)
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
>>> zeros[1][2] = "foo"
>>> print(zeros)
```

is expected to return:

```
>>> print(zeros)
[['foo', 'foo', 'foo'], ['foo', 'foo', 'foo']]
```

but instead returns:

```
>>> print(zeros)
[[0, 0, 'foo'], [0, 0, 'foo']]
```

**So why does the second `*` operator populate each row with references to the same object, but each of the elements WITHIN any given row are unique objects?**

## Answer

[List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

### tl;dr:

Integers are immutable, so `[0]*3` creates copies the elements of [0], not references. However [0,0,0] is an object, so `[0,0,0]*2` creates a new reference to the original object.

Comment: You're changing the reference at the index not changing the referenced object at that index when assigning to a list index

Comment: @IainShelvington Can you please elaborate? It looks like you are referring to 3x separate concepts in your comment, and in each case I am not clear on what you are referring to: `1// changing the reference at the index`, `2// changing the referenced object at that index`, `3//  assigning to a list index`

Comment: "If the * operator populates each row with references to the same object, then why doesn't every element within each row refer to the same object?" **they absolutely do**. You can check this for yourself. `zeros = [[0]*width]*height` then `[id(z) for zs in zeros for z in zs]`

Comment: @chrispalmo "Integers are immutable, so [0]*3 creates copies the elements of [0], not references." **no absolutely incorrect**. It **never, ever creates a copy**. The *type* of the object is irrelevant. Why would it create a copy for immutable elements? that's *exactly backwards* of what you would expect a runtime to do.

Comment: This is totally wrong. `[0, 0, 0]` is an object, a list object, `0` is an object, an `int` object, **everything in python is an object**. Read the edits I added to my answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The fundamental disconnect here is that you believe:

```
zeros[1][2] = "foo"
```

Is *mutating the element in the rows. It isn't. It is mutating the *list* at `zeros[1]`, which happens to be the same list at `zeros[0]`.

*You can't mutate int objects*. Although, they are, in fact, the same int objects:

```
>>> zeros = [[0]*2]*2
>>> zeros
[[0, 0], [0, 0]]
>>> [[id(x) for x in zs] for zs in zeros]
[[4413403792, 4413403792], [4413403792, 4413403792]]
```

So, using `int` objects might actually obscure this, since you might have heard that *small integers are cached in CPython*. They are always the same object. But consider a user-defined class (which is mutable):

```
>>> from dataclasses import dataclass
>>> @dataclass
... class Foo:
...     foo: int
...
>>> fs = [[Foo(0)]*2]*3
>>> fs
[[Foo(foo=0), Foo(foo=0)], [Foo(foo=0), Foo(foo=0)], [Foo(foo=0), Foo(foo=0)]]
>>> fs[0][0].foo = 8
>>> fs
[[Foo(foo=8), Foo(foo=8)], [Foo(foo=8), Foo(foo=8)], [Foo(foo=8), Foo(foo=8)]]
```

So note, with the zeros example, there *is no method we can call*:

```
zeros[0][0].some_method()
```

Such that the `int` object at `zeros[0][0]` would be mutated, as would happen in the equivalent case of `fs[0][0].foo = 8`, because `int` objects *don't expose mutator methods*. That is what *immutable means by definition*.